# Example of G-invariant ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, group-actions, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

**Definition:**
Let $G$ be a group acting on $R_n:=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with
$$\begin{aligned}
G\times R_n &\rightarrow R_n\\
(g,f) &\mapsto f^g
\end{aligned}
$$
where $(f^g)$ acts on a point $p$ in the follow way:
$$(f^g)(p)=f(g\cdot p)$$
Let $I\subset R_n$ an ideal. $I$ is a *G-invariant ideal* if and only if for all $g \in G$ and for all $f \in I$, then $f^g \in I$.

**Goals:** My aim is to look for an example of such an ideal, for $R_n$ and $G$ fixed.

---

The most immediate thing that came to my mind is to take $G:=S_n$.
But then which ideal of $R_n$ can I take to be $G$-invariant?

Comment: I am a bit confused. It looks like the description you gave is incomplete. What exactly do the notes say? It looks to me that they say that any $p,q$ can be written as the sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric polynomial, and then they investigate the conditions on $p$, $q$ such that $I$ is invariant. Also, one should be careful: (1) in general, $a$ and $b$ are elements of $K[x,y]$, too. (2) Shouldn't symmetric mean that $s_j(x,y) = s_j(y,x)$ and skew-symmetric that $k_j(x,y) = -k_j(y,x)$? Please clarify.

Comment: For the second part, you're right: I got confused. I changed what was written thank you. 
For the first part, I don't know. The teacher left it to us to find an example, giving this as input. But I can't understand and prove the invariance of I, do I have to put conditions on p and q? If so, which ones?

Comment: $0$ and $R$ are invariant ideals. Homogeneous polynomials generate invariant ideals for the action $f(x)\to f(ax)$ of $k$. Finite groups yield more interesting examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider che polynomials of the form

$h_k(x_1, \dots, x_n)= \sum_{i_1\dots i_k \in [n]} x_{i_1}\dots x_{i_k}$

It is easy to observe that these polynomials are $S_n$ invariants (the action on $h_k$ comes from the action of $S_n$ on the sets of the form $\{i_1\dots i_k\} $)

The ideal generated by the $h_k$ for $k \in [n]$ is $S_n$ invariant.

Comment: Excuse me, but $\langle h_k \rangle$ isn't equal to $\langle e_k \rangle$ with $e_k$ the $k-$ esim elementary symmetric polynomial?

Comment: Actually the $h_k$ are exactly the elementary symmetric polynomials.